# How can I get the number of the attribute value？

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to assign the value of id to the value of the class attribute and then determine if the class exists, but how do I write it?

```js
var id = 2;
var div1 = ($("#div1").hasClass("'treegrid-parent-'+id"));

if (div1) {
   console.log("true");
} else {
   console.log("false");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="treegrid-parent-2">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there ;-)

```js
var id = 2;
var div1 = ($("#div1").hasClass('treegrid-parent-' + id));

if (div1) {
   console.log("true");
} else {
   console.log("false");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="treegrid-parent-2">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this one.

```
var $div = $("#div")
    id = $div.text()
    div1 = $div.hasClass("treegrid-parent-" + id))
```

Comment: Please don't pimp your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution using ES6 template literals.

```js
var id = 2;
var div1 = ($("#div1").hasClass(`treegrid-parent-${id}`));

if (div1) {
   console.log("true");
} else {
   console.log("false");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="treegrid-parent-2">2</div>
```